# Is there LoadStore memory barrier before volatile write in JAVA

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

In JSR 133 cook book http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

In the chapter of inserting barriers:

> -Issue a StoreStore barrier before each volatile store.
>
> -Issue a StoreStore barrier after all stores but before return from any constructor for any class with a final field.
>
> -Issue a StoreLoad barrier after each volatile store.
>
> -Issue LoadLoad and LoadStore barriers after each volatile load.
>
> -Issue an ExitEnter barrier either before each MonitorEnter or after each MonitorExit.
>
> -Issue EnterLoad and EnterStore barriers after each MonitorEnter.
>
> -Issue StoreExit and LoadExit barriers before each MonitorExit.
>
> -If on a processor that does not intrinsically provide ordering on indirect loads, issue a LoadLoad barrier before each load of a final
> fields.

But, no loadstore barrier before volatile write? So load can be reordered after volatile write?

So the following won't work?

```
Init a = 3
V = false

Thread1
x = a
V = true

Thread2
If (V equal true)
    a = -1
```

Where V is volatile and a is an ordinary var.

Thread 1 may read a to x as -1?
This obey the happen before rule because if Thread2 read V as ture, x = a happen before a = -1?

Comment: *Thread 1 may read of x as -1?*: thread 1 doesn't read x at all in your example.

Comment: sorry, i mean read a to x as -1.. @JBNizet

Comment: Do note that the JSR 133 *Cookbook* is meant for compiler developers and is a *conservative approximation* of the JMM. Programmers shouldn't rely on its semantics because a JVM may implement more relaxed semantics. You might want to take a look at gil tene's [cookbook  for java devs](http://giltene.github.io/DeveloperJMMCookbook/) instead

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question but couldn't find the answer, so I asked the author and here is his reply, "the reason it omitted LoadStore in the case you ask is that it is always covered by the trailing StoreLoad. (True only for volatiles, and using the post-store vs pre-load full fence mappings considered here)"

My understanding:
'Issue a StoreLoad barrier after each volatile store', the StoreLoad on every architecture is implemented by full memory fence (you can check this in the Multiprocessors part on the same page), so all previous loads can't be reordered with loads/stores following volatile store.