# Why there is no LoadStore barrier before volatile write in Java (JSR-133 ordering rules)

Tags: java, jvm, memory-barriers

The JMM rules listed in [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers"](https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) state that Normal Load and Normal Store can not be reordered with volatile-Store after them. To do so, they issue a StoreStore barrier before volatile-write. However, I can't understand why there is no LoadStore barrier before a volatile-Store? If no LoadStore barrier is added before the volatile-Store, a volatile-Store may reorder with a normal-Load before it, and that breaks the rule.

I've read a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957237/is-there-loadstore-memory-barrier-before-volatile-write-in-java). But I still can't make it clear why only StoreStore barrier is added before a volatile-Store.

-------------------------------------UPDATED---------------------------

To make my question clear, I post a picture of code block in [The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers"](https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVT3W.png). In this code block, I think there should be a LoadStore barrier right before "store v" and "store u" to prevent the reorder of normal-Load and volatile-Store. However, there is no such barrier right before "store v" and "store u".

Comment: Where are you seeing that there isn't a LoadStore barrier between a plain load and a `volatile` store?   The JSR-133 page you linked shows such barriers, e.g. in the `class X {
  int a, b;
  volatile int v, u;` example, there's a LoadStore barrier after the last load (which happens to be volatile) before the next volatile store (`store v`).  It's not right before it because it's also needed to order `load u` ahead of non-volatile `store a`.  And this hypothetical compiler is optimizing, not redoing barriers where order is already established by an earlier one, unlike current C++ compilers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I didn't find LoadStore barrier right before "store v". Instead, I noticed there is a LoadStore right after "load u". 
So, Do you mean " there is a LoadStore before 'store v' although they are not next to each other" ? Sounds a little strange to me...

Comment: So that is the code block you're asking about?  You didn't mention any specific part of the large page you linked.  There's a LoadStore barrier between the load and the store that isn't allowed to reorder with it.  A compiler can easily see that this is sufficient by looking backwards from the `volatile` store and seeing that it encounters a LoadStore barrier before getting to any load.  This prevents it the store from reordering with any earlier loads.

Comment: If you were compiling for AArch64, you'd want to try to use `stlr`, a release-store, instead of separate barriers at all, though.  Separate barriers are more expensive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my question. From your explanation, there should be a LoadStore barrier before 'store u' (labeled c) and 'store v' (labeled b). However, there's a LoadStore barrier after 'load u' (labeled a) (before 'store u' and 'store v'). So these LoadStore barriers merged to one, which is after the 'load u' (before 'store u' and 'store v'). Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If you were naively compiling each `volatile` operation separately, you'd put barriers before and after each store.  (Or on ISAs that support it, use a store instruction that has sufficient ordering itself.)

Comment: Thanks! I have another confusion about this explanation. In the "Inserting Barriers" section of the "The JSR-133 Cookbook for Compiler Writers". It is said to "Issue a StoreStore barrier before each volatile store". The author(s) didn't say to add LoadStore barrier before each volatile store Why they ignore it?

Comment: Seems like a mistake.  Maybe they forgot about it, or thought that StoreStore would include LoadStore?  Their table of mappings to processors includes a column for each of the other 3 types, but not LoadStore.  Many ISAs provide LoadStore as part of the same barrier as StoreStore, e.g. PowerPC `lwsync` (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  But their own table shows StoreStore as ARM `dmb st`, which is truly only StoreStore, not LoadStore, which is why 32-bit ARM sucks at this vs. AArch64 and has to use full barriers most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually *is* a LoadStore barrier between `load u` and `store v`; there are no earlier loads (volatile) `store v` could reorder with.

The code-gen is from a hypothetical optimizing compiler that avoids redundant barriers.  e.g. when emitting code for that `volatile` store, scan backwards within this basic block, and if it encounters a LoadStore that's older than any load, don't emit a LoadStore barrier before the actual `store`.

In this case, the  LoadStore barrier was emitted in the process of compiling (volatile) `load u` ahead of (non-volatile) `store a`.

If you were naively compiling each `volatile` operation separately (like [current C++ compilers](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html)), you would indeed put barriers directly before (and directly after) each store.

(Or on ISAs that support it, use a store instruction that has sufficient ordering itself, like AArch64 `stlr`, with `ldar` for `volatile` loads: they can't StoreLoad reorder with each other, but `stlr` *can* StoreLoad reorder with other loads.  This is sufficient for sequential-consistency if you use `volatile` for all shared data that doesn't have other synchronization.  Unlike barriers, load or store operations only need 1-way ordering except.  This makes seq_cst memory ordering cheaper, not having to drain the store buffer for seq_cst stores, unless you do an seq_cst load soon after.)

Later in the page you linked, there's a **Removing Barriers** section describing when you can collapse a pair of barriers, depending on intervening operations.  So the other way to get this result would be to generate naive code and then apply those steps to find redundancy.  Although that table doesn't mention LoadStore barriers.